# Javascript Event Listener only works one time

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding why the following code only runs one time.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Been stumped on this one for a couple days now:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#myBtn");
var clickCount = 0;

function myFunction() {
    clickCount++;
    document.body.innerHTML += "<br><br>Button was clicked " + clickCount + " time(s)";
    console.log("Button was clicked " + clickCount + " time(s)");
}

button.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <head><script src="script.js" defer></script></head>
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Don't use `body.innerHTML += ...` to add elements, because this overwrites the entire existing body and in effect recreates the DOM *without* your event handler. You can use [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead, or if you really want the simplicity of appending a string of HTML then use `.innerHTML += ...` on a specific element rather than on the whole body.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I created a div element within the body to act on instead and it's working as expected now.  I'm still a little puzzled, however, as to why it wouldn't at least work on the console.log portion.  On a side note, I realized too that I was putting the head tag inside the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @nnnnnnn,

> Don't use body.innerHTML += ... to add elements, because this
>   overwrites the entire existing body and in effect recreates the DOM

You can add a new div like this `<div id="msg"></div>` in your body that will show your button click event messages.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#myBtn");
var clickCount = 0;

function myFunction() {
  clickCount++;
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += "<br><br>Button was clicked " + clickCount + " time(s)";
  console.log("Button was clicked " + clickCount + " time(s)");
}

button.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <head><script src="script.js" defer></script></head>
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
<div id="msg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @nnnnnnn!  Followed your suggestion.  Working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

You are nuking the listener you attached by doing `body.innerHTML +=`. Here is what you can try to prevent that:

`document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br><br>Button was clicked " + clickCount + " time(s)");`

`insertAdjacentHTML` is fast and reliable.

You can also try `appendChild` but that would mean you have an `HTMLElement` to append.

Comment: Thank you, sir!  I'm unfamiliar with the insertAdjacentHTML method, but I'll start experimenting with it.